# Azure AD Connect to sync multiple-Forests

Tags: azure

I have 2 AD Forests with no trust relationship. I want to synchronize Forest 1 for password replication and Forest 2 for Federation into a single Azure AD tenant.

How to achieve this?

Do I have to setup ADFS for Forest 2 prior to start Azure AD sync?

How to configure Azure AD Connect, do I need to use express setting or custom setting, what options to configure please?

I understand I cannot have 2 x Azure AD Connect Servers, one with express setting to use password replication and another one with federation as this is not a supported topology.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

you'd do the following:

- Use Azure AD Connect (custom option) to sync both forests
- Set up ADFS through Azure AD Connect.
- You also choose pwd sync for both forests as you can't restrict it to one through the wizard.
- You configure federation settings only for the domain that you want federation for.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-get-started-custom/ is a good article for you to go through.

Thanks //Sam (@MrADFS)

Comment: Thanks Sam. Is there a way to stop replicating passwords for the Forest where we have configured ADFS?Any Powershell cmdlet to turn off password sync on the forest using adfs?